# PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one

I have a many to one mapping with two classes (code is reduced):

Category:

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    String name;
```

Subcategory:

```
@Entity
public class Subcategory {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SUBCATEGORY_ID")
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    Long categoryId;

    @NotNull
    String name;
```

When I try to add subcategory to existing category, I get

```
ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component SubcategoryController for method public void %package%.SubcategoryController.add(%package%.Subcategory): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of %package%.Category.id
...
    at %package%.SubcategoryController$$$view1.add(Unknown Source)
...
    at %package%.SubcategoryController$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.add(SubcategoryController$Proxy$_$$_Weld$Proxy$.java)
    at %package%.SubcategoryService.add(SubcategoryService.java:30)
    at %package%.SubcategoryService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.add(SubcategoryService$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
...
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of %package%.Category.id
```

What should I do to awoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

In your category class it should be an OneToMany annotation like this :

```
@Entity
public class Category {    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
    Long id;    
    @NotNull
    String name;        
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    List<Subcategory> subcategories;    
}
```

You might also want to check out:
*[www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/)*

Comment: I analyzed given example and found that changing `Long categoryId` to `Category category` will be enough, but this doesn't solve my problem. Are there any solutions yet (I don't need list of childs in parent class)?

Comment: @OneToMany fields are optional, hibernate will NOT generate an exception if you do not use them.

Answer (score 0):

Situations where this exception might occur:

**1)** name of database table is incorrect or missing:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category_table")    // name of database table
public class Category
```

**2)**  Field class doesn't match the target class:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Category.class)   // Target class
@JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID")
Category categoryId;                        // Target field
```

In your case `categoryId` is of type `Long`, and hibernate is trying to insert `Category.class` fields into `categoryId` but can't.